# SQL Change from Decimal to Text

Tags: sql, opencart

I am using OpenCart for a pizza restaurant and I need to add more than one price to the catalog page. I am looking now for someone to create all the mods I need for it but in the meantime I want to simply be able to add a line of text in lieu of adding a dollar amount for the price. In the database the settings under column>price are as follows:

```
Type: DECIMAL, 
Length/Values: 15,2, 
Default: as Defined, 0.00
```

When I try to add the following (which is what I would like until I can get the mods built): $7.95 / $10.95 it defaults to the decimal. I changed the settings to Text and tried some settings but I really don't know what I am doing. Can anyone tell me how I can make this happen? Perhaps if I could even add another field in the admin area and call that field in lieu of the text field? They will not offer online ordering for a couple weeks so I need a quick fix until the mods are done. Thanks.

Comment: Why not add a one to many relationship from the catalog item to prices and handle the formatting in the view? That way you still have strongly-typed data in the DB that will not need to be cleaned up later.

Comment: Really you d not want to do that, it will mess up any math that you do with the price (like say tax calculations). Any time you want to do something like this is its a clue you are doing somethign worng. The price is not 7.95/10.95 as that is meaningless interms of price. You may need to two records one for teh 7.95 proce and one for the 10.95 price. But never attempt to put data in a field that doesn't makes sense in terms of what the field will be used for. You will thank us late when you don't have to figure out what price "to be determined" meant when someone ordered it.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice and input. I know that but ordering is not available right now. Even if ordering were available, when people click on the item title, or the "add to order" they are taken to a page that has the correct price data. Creating anything like what you guys are talking about is way over my head. That is why I want to hire someone to do it. I need all sorts of other functionality for delivery, tips, pizza toppings, etc. I just need a quick fix for the next two weeks so I can display the prices without having to list every small/large item separately. Thanka again:-)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments i understood that you need two prices for a small and large pizza for example, if that is the case options are your solution, as they are used exactly for that to have the same product in different sizes and prices in your case, users just have to specify the option they need.

Also here is a tutorial that will guide you: http://www.opencarttutorial.com/how-to-setup-your-opencart-catalog/product-options/

Comment: I know how to use options. That is not the problem. I need 2 prices to display on the catalog page. That is not possible currently. I can set a price for the small pizza and add$ if they opt to get a large, but I need the category page to list a price for the small, and a price for the large. Thank you for your input though, I appreciate it.

Comment: if you want to add these info in the category page, you should tweak category.php controller to get option data for specific product_id and then afterwards simply call the added variabel in the category.tpl, if you use standard theme with no change to your controllers i could try and see if i can find a quick function for you. Although i do not know if you would like this approach

Comment: Thank you very much Jonid. I just removed set the price div to display:none for now and added the prices in the product title. I really appreciate the advice and the offer though. It took me forever to change everything and will take me forever again. I will try to learn how to do what you are explaining though. I just have enough trouble with CSS right now but I am learning quickly thanks to forums like this and people like you. It actually is a custom theme anyway. Thanks again so much and have a great day.